# Setting expiry time in bulk upload in redis

Tags: python, redis

I am using [Redis.mset](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/redis/client.html#Redis.mset) to bulk upload all key-value pairs.

In [Redis.set](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#redis.Redis.set), I can see an option to set expiry time via `ex` or `px`

```
def set(self, name, value, ex=None, px=None, nx=False, xx=False):
```

While no such option exists for mset.

If I want to set expiry time (which is same for all the key-value pairs), 
is looping over `set` the only option?

Comment: I believe it is true that looping over `set` is the only way as Redis itself doesn't support setting what you want on `mset` method: https://redis.io/commands/mset

Comment: You could try pipelining. See if it helps